# jQuery UI Datepicker opens up on clicks outside of the appropriate input

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I've it reproduced it in the js fiddle below. Make sure to make the "result" pain wide enough so that the two inputs are on one line.

https://jsfiddle.net/4191hnq9/5/

Then click to left of the blue container, and the datepicker for the right input will open. Make sure you click on the horizontal plane of the inputs.

If I remove the top container div:

```
 <div class="container" style="background-color:blue">
```

Then the issue goes away. However I can't do this because my partial view is being rendered inside of a container.

Any idea why?

Edit: issue seems to only be present with Chrome.

Comment: Sorry my external resources got list in the jsfiddle. Working on it.

Comment: I just added the missing external resources and tried it, and it worked fine. I'll wait until you update yours.

Comment: You know what, I think it's a chrome issue. I opened it in IE and I don't have the issue.

Comment: I tried it on firefox and had no problem there. Chrome is usually pretty good about stuff so that seems a little odd to me. If you post your updated fiddle I can take another look anyway if you'd like.

Comment: I updated the fiddle link. Let me know if it's not working for you. It should have the resources.

Comment: The datepickers didn't display correctly because you forgot jquery-ui.css, but they didn't open when I clicked outside of their text boxes. which is how they are supposed to function. Code-wise, I don't see anything that you're doing wrong. All of your tags are properly closed and everything, so as far as I can tell it's probably a browser issue like you said.